# Can Google Cloud Endpoints run in a App Engine Module?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

dear all

I'm trying to create a [App Engine Module](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) for hosting my api server developed with [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/). The endpoint I developed runs well in local dev environment but it responds notFound error after I deployed to remote and test it. I was guessing this might be caused by the fact that endpoints are run in a non-default module. Not sure though. Here is my module definition file (api-server.yaml):

```
    application: myapp
    module: api-server
    version: dev
    runtime: python27
    instance_class: F2
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true
    automatic_scaling:
      max_idle_instances: 5


    handlers:
    - url: /_ah/spi/.*
      script: api_dispatch.application

    libraries:
    - name: endpoints
      version: 1.0
```

I plan to host endpoints with module cause my api server actually share a lot of code with my default module, which is a normal web app. Please let me know if it's possible. And sample code is very welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just deployed my api server to a standalone app engine instance and it works well. So it seems to me that endpoints can't work well with app engine module yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's supported. I don't know why the problem happened before. But it starts working now.

Comment: Hi James, I have a similar problem and you seem to have solved it according to this topic. Could you please tell me more about how you did that exactly? I still have problems with separating the API module from the default one. See my unanswered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232580/putting-a-cloud-endpoints-api-in-a-separate-app-engine-module. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Romain In case you weren't able to figure it out, I was able to get it to work locally by starting two instances of `dev_appservers`, where one only launched my API module. Hope this helps.